# What is the difference between Lord Ayyappa and Sri Dharma Sastha?

Tags: ayyappa

I've often seen the names, Lord Ayyappa and Sri Dharma Sastha. Lord Ayyappa is the Son of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu (Mohini).But what are the differences between them? Are Lord Ayyappa and Sri Dharma Sastha the same?

Comment: Ayyappa refers to prince Manikandan of Pandalam, who was a human incarnation of the god Dharma Shasta.  Dharma Shasta was born long ago, when Mohini Avatara happened.  Ayyappa was born relatively recently; a friend/devoteee of his was a Muslim general named Vavar.

Comment: both are same ..

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan - Could you elaborate your comment and convert this to a proper answer format with references?

Comment: @Rakesh - I don't think so

Comment: @KiranRS if you already know then why the question

Comment: @KiranRS Title spelling error Aastha for Sastha?

Comment: 'Shaastaa' literally means 'one who governs/rules' and 'Dharma Shaastaa' literally means 'one who governs and rules with Dharma'. So it could have been appropriated by multiple people at different times in history.

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of question which should be answered by the yogis or those who are in those lines, those who converse with the divine power, rather than scholars who read books which itself is many times altered and wild and creative imagination for a noble purpose. As per the tantrik beliefs, both are different, one born as a human, and the other is siva-narayana chaithanya. The truth is more bitter, so better, be with the Sastha form. So, in temple worships, Sastha form only has to be worshiped, as this can often lead to many issues, those who know this, will keep this with them, to avoid confusion to common lot.

Answer (score 1):

Theoritically they are different.

**Ayyappan** was the adopted son of the king of pandalam, actually the son of Shiva and Mohini. He was a Nitya Bramhachari. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyappan)

But **Dharma Sastha** means a man who has the power to make and implement dharmas or righteousness in the society. He also has 2 wives. (http://vipasana-vidushika.blogspot.in/2013/05/ayyappa-as-dharma-sastha.html)

The problem arises because of Sabarimala Ayyappa temple being named and also conducting poojas on Dharma Sastha